# Can't load content inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load some content inside a div `#display`. I have read many questions regarding this matter here, but still I have been unable to get it working. The `alert` function which I have just added for testing purpose works without any problem.

Here is what I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#townships').click(function() {
        $('#display').load("helloworld.html");
            alert("Hi");
        });
    });
```

I am trying this offline. The `helloworld.html` file is in the same folder with the homepage file.

Comment: Can you add your HTML here too?

Comment: Have you included jQuery library?

Comment: Do you want me to add the html code of helloworld.html here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying this offline

I believe this is your problem. AJAX requests to the local filesystem will be blocked by the browsers' security settings.

You need to run it under a webserver, either on your local machine, such as WAMP/LAMP/IIS or on a remote machine.

Comment: I set up a WAMP server, as you suggested, and now it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do AJAX request without loading files from some server. Doing it by loading files from file system won't work because of SAME ORIGIN policy. Since there is no domain to compare to the AJAX requests fail. You can see the exception while doing it in Chrome.

This is relevant

[AJAX code do not run locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998192/ajax-code-do-not-run-locally)

Answer (score 0):

You should put your html file in a web server. If you have python installed, you can just type

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]``
```

In order to have a rapid web server in your working directory.