# "MLHttpRequest cannot load file: ///path/to/file.html" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load a local html file in a div when a certain pressed with the following jquery load command.

```
$("#div_name").load("local_html_file");
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
MLHttpRequest cannot load file:///path/to/file.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm not running any special servers. Just running my html files with Chrome. I searched it and kind of know what the problem is but don't know how to solve it.

Comment: That's considered a security violation.

Comment: What you can do is to use JSONP, or set up a local server.

Comment: the title does not reflect your question/problem

Comment: Setup a local server - if you have PHP installed for instance, just run `php -S localhost:8000`, in the folder you want to serve your files from, then point your browser to `http://localhost:8000` et voilà.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found an answer which is to put the second html file on a apache server.

Comment: The original problem was that I couldn't put everything there because I'm loading some (a lot) local images and there are some security/privacy concerns to keep them locally.

Comment: To those thumbs downs, I hate you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jquery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method is an ajax call.

That's why it will not work locally... You need to run it on a server that will accept HttpRequest's.

It's been discussed before:

- [Jquery: Running AJAX locally without a webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397644/jquery-running-ajax-locally-without-a-webserver)
- [AJAX code do not run locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998192/ajax-code-do-not-run-locally)

Comment: You won't need a server for that. It's client side.

Comment: Well since he used a URL fragment, the browser will implicitly turn it into a `file://` URL relative to the main page's URL, but it still won't work.

Comment: @CasBloem - Yes you do.